# auto vertical and horizontal alignment in Grid WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Let's say that I have a grid which has a lot of buttons what I want to achieve is I want to align the button in the top left corner and when I change the size of the window the size of the grid will change and the buttons will be rearranged automatically. 
My XAML code would be like

```
<Grid  HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">

        <Grid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="100" />
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="100" />

            </Style>

        </Grid.Resources>
        <Button Content="Button1" />
        <Button Content="Button2" />
        <Button Content="Button3" />
        <Button Content="Button4" />
        <Button Content="Button5" />
        <Button Content="Button6" />

    </Grid>
```

I'm a web developer and it's super easy to do it in CSS & HTML.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gGdrJJ

Comment: [`WrapPanel`](https://wpftutorial.net/WrapPanel.html)?

Comment: That actually worked , well I am super surprised cause I did a lot of search , thank you anyway .

Comment: You might have missed [Panels Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/panels-overview).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry the question was easy the answer is WrapPanel 
this link  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/panels-overview 
would be useful for starters